# SQLiteDatabase hosted on server android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application that uses the `SQLiteDatabase` as its database, because each application has its own, custom database (well, custom values), for another app I am making, I want to hose a single `SQLiteDatabase` that every app will access, for example one app adds a row, while another then reads it at a later time.

Is there anyway to do this? Everything I've found has left me believing there is not, but there has to be.

Any ideas?

Update:
I'm not sure if you've quite understood what I'm trying to do, sorry. The apps accessing this db are all the "same" app, but from different phones, for example, the database could be used to store a user id and their favorite color, so another phone could search their user id, and get the color in db with that user id –

I'm sorry if I did not make that clear enough

Comment: I am a bit confused are you trying to sync the database across all phones or each phone has a different database?

Comment: all phones, like if I'm creating a trial version of an app and giving out one-time activation codes so i'd query WHERE id = ____ then if it s there, remove it and activate the phone, or having like "status" messages synced across a messaging application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is way to do it! There is always a way!

Anywho, what I think you are looking for is a remote server. These can be done in a few way depending on how much money you have.

(1)If you're broke like me all the time, then you can make an extra computer you have at home act as a server for your app. This can cause a few ( :) hehe few) security issues for your home though. Also you will have a lot of traffic on your home network.

(2)Another option it's to get a domain name and web host. Most of the web hosting services I have seen offer database support. So what you could do is hop on, create your database on the web host server then link your app to your server. The cost on that varies based on your needs.

Really though, is your app interfacing with mulitple people? I can't think of a reason you would want this feature on any other phone (device) than your (relative to us customers) device. I rarely hand my device over to others, and never unless it's locked.

Comment: I've already gotten my homeserver set up to host the db file, and I can download it, but I cant access it

Comment: @Samuel - Then you just need to create a front end. And your question should be more inline of 'How do I create a front end for my home database'.

Comment: Take a look at this. It should help you out more specifically. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: pointed me in the right direction, still working on the solution however

Comment: instead of export the mysql directly to net, might be better to hack up some simple php scripts that return query in XML or JSON in your httpd server.

Answer (score 0):

[**SQLite is serverless**](http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html). In a situation as described there are **no** guarantees that it will work properly. Your solution is to create a **database server** that will cater to multiply Android clients simultaneously.

For more information on SQLite see [LinuxForu.com](http://www.linuxforu.com/how-to/networking/lighttpd-and-sqlite-a-lightweight-web-server-and-database-platform/) and/or SQLite.org